# Add a "0" to the left of the postal code

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, if

I would like to put a formula in a flow to update the postal code if it only contains 4 characters.
All my postcodes must be 5 characters long so I would like to add a 0 to all the postcodes that are less than 9999.

Below is the formula that I have started to work on but I don't know if it is correct. I have an error : (extra ',')

```
IF({!$Record.PointofSale__PostalCode__s}<'9999', LPAD(TEXT({!$Record.PointofSale__PostalCode__s}), 4,0))  , {!$Record.PointofSale__PostalCode__s})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work as you expect, because you're comparing strings. Every postal code will be less than '9999' except for '99990' through '99999'. But you've already stumbled across the answer: LPAD.

```
LPAD({!$Record.PointofSale__PostalCode__s},5,'0')
```

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox it works

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `LPAD(TEXT({!$Record.PointofSale__PostalCode__s}), 5, '0')`

Note that the last argument in the formula has to be text, so it needs to be in quotes.

Comment: I tried that before posting my message. Salesforce error : The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Extra ')'

Comment: Sorry try it now